# Close someone else's code review TFS 2015

Tags: tfs

I am in charge of a team of developers that has experienced a high rate of turnover.  I have 100 some code reviews in "requested" status because the developer didn't close them before leaving the company.  I took ownership of these in TFS by right clicking and assigning to myself, but it is not giving me the option of closing.

According to [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/68a1e795-dd86-4da4-9270-1484974d450e/how-to-close-someone-elses-code-review-request?forum=tfsgeneral) I should be able to download an excel sheet and do a "bulk" update:

> Please try this workaround: create a work query to get all that user’s Code Review Request work items which in Requested state, save this work item query and open this query in Excel, then edit them work items in Excel to change the state to Closed, then click Publish button to publish the updates to TFS Server.

I do not see any way to do this either.

What are my options here?

Comment: I am actively using the above solution to cleanup from time to time. Why is it not working for you?

Comment: I can't find an option to export to excel even

Comment: @ToreØstergaard yep, i was trying to do this with a browser

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All code review requests are in fact a TFS work item. You can close them in bulk by bulk updating them using Excel, just as you would do for any other work item.

The way to do is to open your code reviews query from the link on the top right of Code Reviews section in Team Explorer

[image]

Once you are in query mode, click on "Save query" to save your code review query. Now click on the "Open query in Excel" button

[image]

This would open up an excel sheet for you. Change the State of each of code review work item that you would like to update. Then click on the the Team menu and use the "Publish" button to make your changes in TFS.

[image]

Comment: I was trying to use the web version of this, but it was failing.  Luckily this version worked perfectly!  Thank you