# TFS Code review: Can we restrict a code review to be closed by the reviewer

Tags: tfs, tfs-code-review

We use TFS for code review. Now the user who creates only can close the review. We need a process where the reviewer only can close the review.

Once the review is created, the reviewer and the developer should be able to communicate back and forth using comments and replies.

At the end if everything looks good, the reviewer will verify and close the review.

Comment: Reviewers and developers can already communicate back and forth and the shelveset associated with the review can be updated any time as well. I think what's more important is adding a gate to your check-ins rather than worrying about who closes a review.

Answer (score 0):

It's able to close someone else's code review. All code review requests are in fact a TFS work item. You can close them in bulk by bulk updating them using Excel, just as you would do for any other work item.

1. Create a work query to get all that user’s Code Review Request work
   items which in Requested state
2. Save this work item query and open this query in Excel, then edit
   them work items in Excel to change the state to Closed,
3. Then click Publish button to publish the updates to TFS Server.

> The way to do is to open your code reviews query from the link on the
>   top right of Code Reviews section in Team Explorer
>
> [image]
>
> Once you are in query mode, click on "Save query" to save your code
>   review query. Now click on the "Open query in Excel" button
>
> [image]
>
> This would open up an excel sheet for you. Change the State of each of
>   code review work item that you would like to update. Then click on the
>   the Team menu and use the "Publish" button to make your changes in
>   TFS.
>
> [image]

More details please refer this thread: [Close someone else's code review TFS 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47266726/close-someone-elses-code-review-tfs-2015)

You could not restrict the user who created the code review to close code review. However, you could  enforce Code Review before check-in time by using **check-in policy**. Once the code review failed, the user could not be able to check in his code. You could either [write your own custom check-in policy](https://blog.devart.com/creating-tfs-custom-check-in-policy-part-1.html) or directly use 3-rd extensions--[Colin's ALM Checkin Policies VS 2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ColinD.ColinsALMCheckinPoliciesVS2017).